# Spring Hibernate not-null property references a null or transient value: com.klisman.model.Usuario.estadoId

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

If I try register a new user in my system I am getting an exception

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "senha")
    private String senha;

    @JoinColumn(name = "estado_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Estado estadoId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "tipo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tipo tipoId;
```

Tipo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipo")
public class Tipo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tipoId")
    private List<Usuario> usuarioList;</code>
```

Estado

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "estado")
public class Estado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "estadoId")
    private List<Usuario> usuarioList;
```

DAO

```
@Repository
public class UsuarioDaoImpl implements UsuarioDAO {

@Autowired 
private SessionFactory session;

@Override
public void add(Usuario usuario) {
    session.getCurrentSession().save(usuario);
}
```

Service Spring

```
 @Service
 public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements UsuarioService {

 @Autowired
 private UsuarioDAO usuarioDao;
 @Transactional
 public void add(Usuario usuario) {
     usuarioDao.add(usuario);

 }
```

UsuarioController

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioController {
@Autowired
private UsuarioService usuarioService;

@RequestMapping("/usuario")
public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    map.put("usuario", usuario);
    map.put("usuarioList", usuarioService.getAllUsuario());
    return "usuario";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Usuario usuario,
        BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action,
        Map<String, Object> map) {
    Usuario usuarioResult = new Usuario();
    switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
    case "cadastrar":
        usuarioService.add(usuario);
        usuarioResult = usuario;
        break;
    case "alterar":
        usuarioService.edit(usuario);
        usuarioResult = usuario;
        break;
    case "excluir":
        usuarioService.delete(usuario.getId());
        usuarioResult = new Usuario();
        break;
    case "pesquisar":
        Usuario searchedUsuario = usuarioService
                .getUsuario(usuario.getId());
        usuarioResult = searchedUsuario != null ? searchedUsuario
                : new Usuario();
        break;
    }
    map.put("usuario", usuarioResult);
    map.put("usuarioList", usuarioService.getAllUsuario());
    return "usuario";
}
}
```

Page

```
<form:form action="usuario.do" method="POST" commandName="usuario">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td><form:input path="nome"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Senha</td>
            <td><form:input path="senha"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tipo</td>
            <td><form:input path="tipoId"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Estado</td>
            <td><form:input path="estadoId"/></td>
        </tr>                       
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type = "submit" name="action" value="Cadastrar" />
            <input type = "submit" name="action" value="Alterar" />
            <input type = "submit" name="action" value="Excluir" />
            <input type = "submit" name="action" value="Pesquisar" />           
        </tr>   
    </table>
</form:form>
```

The project list fine but if i try to register a new user

not-null property references a null or transient value: com.klisman.model.Usuario.estadoId`

Thanks for you attention

Comment: It would help if you showed the controller method that is used when you post the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is being caused because you aren't setting an `Estado` object to your `Usuario` object. Because you are joining around your `Estado` object's ID and making the relationship required (with your `@ManyToOne(optional=false)` annotation), Hibernate is refusing to save your `Usuario` object because the `Estado` object is missing off it.

In your service layer you need to do something similar to the following:

```
@Transactional
public void add(Usuario usuario, Estado estado, Tipo tipo) {
    usuario.setEstado(estado);
    usuario.setTipo(tipo);
    usuarioDao.add(usuario);
}
```

The above should succeed, assuming that you have the correct `Estado` and `Tipo` objects passed in. This is assuming that your `Estado` and `Tipo` objects already exist in the database, and that you fetched them using their ID's, however if they don't you need to reverse the directions of your cascades so that they get created by cascade when you save your `Usuario` object.

**Edit 1:**
I'm not going to give you a complete example but what I mean is do this:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private EstadoService estadoService;
    @Autowired
    private TipoService tipoService;
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;
```

Then use your other services to get the `Estado` and `Tipo` objects that need to be saved on the `Usuario` object, add them to it, then save the `Usuario` object.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how would the controller with several classes?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but how would the controller with several classes?

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/usuario.do",     method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Usuario usuario,  BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
    Usuario usuarioResult = new Usuario();
    switch(action.toLowerCase()){
    case "cadastrar":
        usuarioService.add(usuario);
        usuarioResult = usuario;
        break;
```

Comment: Autowire the `Estado` and `Tipo` services into the controller and use them to get your objects out of the database.

Comment: @JamesMassey you have a complete example that I can compare? I'm lost

Thank you